# Python pandas stock basket return optimization

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I want to create a script that looks for the optimal time to purchase and sell a basket of stocks over the course of a month,  based on the overall return of the basket.

For example, lets say that stock 1 has the highest return of 8% if I buy on day 2 and sell on day 12, stock 2 has the highest return of 4% if I buy on day 9 and sell on day 15 and stock 3 has the highest return of -1% if I buy on day 1 and sell on day 20. My question is how do you write a script that would look at all return possibilities for all three stocks and come up with an output that produces the highest return for the overall basket of stocks if I had to buy all three stocks on the same day and sell on the same day.

For example, the highest return for all three stocks might be buy on day 4 and sell on day 17 where the overall return for a dollar invested across the board is 7% for stock 1, 3.5% for stock 2 and -1.25% for stock 3. This is based on the fact that we would not be able to get the most optimal return for each stock if all three had to be purchased and sold on the same day.

[image]

Comment: Is this a homework problem?

Comment: No, I realize it is not a forward looking indicator/more of backtesting for a specific group of stocks/sector analysis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sort the df by date.

```
df = df.sort_values(by ='Date', ascending=True)
```

then sum all stocks, daily

```
df['total'] = df[['TSLA Price', 'NVDA Price', 'AAPL Price']].sum(axis=1)
```

then use the following function

```
def max_profit(li):
    max_profit, purchase_on, sell_on = 0, 0, 0
    for i, buy in enumerate(li):
        for j, sell in enumerate(li[i+1:]):
            if sell-buy > max_profit:
                max_profit, purchase_on, sell_on = sell-buy, i, i+j+1
    return max_profit, purchase_on, sell_on

max_profit, purchase_on, sell_on = max_profit(df['total'].tolist())
```

Buy/Sell dates will be...

```
buy_date, sell_date = df['Date'].iloc[purchase_on], df['Date'].iloc[sell_on ]
```

To weight differently just multiply the stocks with the weights and then do the sum.

Comment: Pradeep!  This is great!  This looks fantastic, there is only one issue that I can see- after running the code, it does nail the return as far as max gain between closing prices, however, for some reason it is giving the sale date -1- so for example it accurately states 11/23 as the purchase date, but states 11/30 should be the sale date, and it looks like the calculation takes into consideration 12/3 as sales date for max gain, but lists 11/30 as the sale date-  (correct calculation with correct date, but listing inaccurate sale date when printed)

Comment: Yeah the sell_on should be i+j+1. Corrected

Comment: Pradeep, thank you very much!  You are extremely talented, thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a very old post, but I'll jump in with what I have for you.

```
import pandas as pd  
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import scipy.optimize as sco
import datetime as dt
import math
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from pandas_datareader import data as wb
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
np.random.seed(777)


start = '2018-06-30'
end = '2020-06-30'
# N = 90
# start = datetime.now() - timedelta(days=N)
# end = dt.datetime.today()



tickers = ['AXP','AAPL','BA','CAT','CSCO','CVX','XOM','GS','HD','IBM','INTC','JNJ','KO','JPM','MCD','MMM','MRK','MSFT','NKE','PFE','PG','TRV','UNH','RTX','VZ','V','WBA','WMT','DIS','DOW']

thelen = len(tickers)

price_data = []
for ticker in tickers:
    prices = wb.DataReader(ticker, start = start, end = end, data_source='yahoo')[['Adj Close']]
    price_data.append(prices.assign(ticker=ticker)[['ticker', 'Adj Close']])

df = pd.concat(price_data)
df.dtypes
df.head()
df.shape

pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 500)

df = df.reset_index()
df = df.set_index('Date')
table = df.pivot(columns='ticker')
# By specifying col[1] in below list comprehension
# You can select the stock names under multi-level column
table.columns = [col[1] for col in table.columns]
table.head()

def portfolio_annualised_performance(weights, mean_returns, cov_matrix):
    returns = np.sum(mean_returns*weights ) *252
    std = np.sqrt(np.dot(weights.T, np.dot(cov_matrix, weights))) * np.sqrt(252)
    return std, returns
  
def random_portfolios(num_portfolios, mean_returns, cov_matrix, risk_free_rate):
    results = np.zeros((3,num_portfolios))
    weights_record = []
    for i in range(num_portfolios):
        weights = np.random.random(thelen)
        weights /= np.sum(weights)
        weights_record.append(weights)
        portfolio_std_dev, portfolio_return = portfolio_annualised_performance(weights, mean_returns, cov_matrix)
        results[0,i] = portfolio_std_dev
        results[1,i] = portfolio_return
        results[2,i] = (portfolio_return - risk_free_rate) / portfolio_std_dev
    return results, weights_record


returns = table.pct_change()
mean_returns = returns.mean()
cov_matrix = returns.cov()
num_portfolios = 10000
risk_free_rate = 0.0178



def display_simulated_ef_with_random(mean_returns, cov_matrix, num_portfolios, risk_free_rate):
    results, weights = random_portfolios(num_portfolios,mean_returns, cov_matrix, risk_free_rate)
    
    max_sharpe_idx = np.argmax(results[2])
    sdp, rp = results[0,max_sharpe_idx], results[1,max_sharpe_idx]
    max_sharpe_allocation = pd.DataFrame(weights[max_sharpe_idx],index=table.columns,columns=['allocation'])
    max_sharpe_allocation.allocation = [round(i*100,2)for i in max_sharpe_allocation.allocation]
    max_sharpe_allocation = max_sharpe_allocation.T
    
    min_vol_idx = np.argmin(results[0])
    sdp_min, rp_min = results[0,min_vol_idx], results[1,min_vol_idx]
    min_vol_allocation = pd.DataFrame(weights[min_vol_idx],index=table.columns,columns=['allocation'])
    min_vol_allocation.allocation = [round(i*100,2)for i in min_vol_allocation.allocation]
    min_vol_allocation = min_vol_allocation.T
    
    print("-")
    print("Maximum Sharpe Ratio Portfolio Allocation\n")
    print("Annualised Return:", round(rp,2))
    print("Annualised Volatility:", round(sdp,2))
    print("\n")
    print(max_sharpe_allocation)
    print("-")
    print("Minimum Volatility Portfolio Allocation\n")
    print("Annualised Return:", round(rp_min,2))
    print("Annualised Volatility:", round(sdp_min,2))
    print("\n")
    print(min_vol_allocation)
    
    plt.figure(figsize=(10, 7))
    plt.scatter(results[0,:],results[1,:],c=results[2,:],cmap='YlGnBu', marker='o', s=10, alpha=0.3)
    plt.colorbar()
    plt.scatter(sdp,rp,marker='*',color='r',s=500, label='Maximum Sharpe ratio')
    plt.scatter(sdp_min,rp_min,marker='*',color='g',s=500, label='Minimum volatility')
    plt.title('Simulated Portfolio Optimization based on Efficient Frontier')
    plt.xlabel('annualised volatility')
    plt.ylabel('annualised returns')
    plt.legend(labelspacing=0.8)
    

display_simulated_ef_with_random(mean_returns, cov_matrix, num_portfolios, risk_free_rate)
```

Result:

```
Maximum Sharpe Ratio Portfolio Allocation

Annualised Return: 0.16
Annualised Volatility: 0.25


            AAPL   AXP    BA   CAT  CSCO   CVX   DIS   DOW    GS    HD   IBM  \
allocation  4.76  1.63  1.03  0.26  1.22  0.05  6.86  0.43  1.02  6.42  0.88   

            INTC   JNJ   JPM    KO   MCD   MMM   MRK  MSFT   NKE   PFE    PG  \
allocation  2.56  0.64  4.92  0.27  6.64  4.13  6.99  5.49  4.52  2.35  6.36   

            RTX   TRV   UNH    V    VZ   WBA   WMT  XOM  
allocation  5.3  1.79  0.39  6.8  7.06  0.67  5.98  2.6  
-
Minimum Volatility Portfolio Allocation

Annualised Return: 0.13
Annualised Volatility: 0.24


            AAPL   AXP    BA   CAT  CSCO   CVX   DIS   DOW    GS    HD   IBM  \
allocation  4.43  0.59  0.59  1.01  1.69  0.56  1.04  0.81  0.64  1.44  1.72   

            INTC   JNJ  JPM    KO   MCD   MMM   MRK  MSFT  NKE   PFE    PG  \
allocation  3.43  3.47  2.9  5.43  7.61  4.99  7.78  4.72  2.2  7.13  6.72   

             RTX   TRV   UNH     V    VZ   WBA   WMT   XOM  
allocation  0.47  4.56  2.95  0.47  6.84  7.81  4.76  1.23
```

Finally:

[image]

There are other things you can attempt as well.  Check out the link below for all details.

https://github.com/ASH-WICUS/Notebooks/blob/master/Portfolio%20Optimization.ipynb